# Access cognito user pool and getting user token

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, amazon-cognito

how to get user token from cognito in windows application (winform ) c# . thanks in advance.

i tried

```
Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(
                 new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials(), Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
userPool = new CognitoUserPool("", "", provider)
```

Comment: what is the _cognitoService ? from which namespace need to  include .

Answer (score 1):

There is a [C# example in the AWS SDK Code Examples library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cognito-identity-provider_example_cognito-identity-provider_Scenario_SignUpUserWithMfa_section.html) that demonstrates working with a user pool. You can clone the repo and run the example yourself. There is an Admin Login piece there that is similar to what you'll need if you are doing a user (not admin) login. This setup uses an auth challenge which you can ignore if you aren't using that option.

```
public async Task<InitiateAuthResponse> InitiateAuthAsync(string clientId, string userName, string password)
{
    var authParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    authParameters.Add("USERNAME", userName);
    authParameters.Add("PASSWORD", password);

    var authRequest = new InitiateAuthRequest

    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        AuthParameters = authParameters,
        AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
    };

    var response = await _cognitoService.InitiateAuthAsync(authRequest);
    Console.WriteLine($"Result Challenge is : {response.ChallengeName}");

    return response;
}
```

Comment: what is the _cognitoService ? from which namespace need to include

Comment: In this case it is the IAmazonCognitoIdentityProvider that is injected by the DI engine. That example shows you how to set that up. You can look at the full example in the code library (or better yet, clone the repo: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples).